# Cannot boot live cd, various errors(sometimes kernel panic, sometimes it goes to busybox)

Tags: live-cd, kernel

I want to install **Ubuntu 10.04.2** on laptop, but first time I run Ubuntu live CD it runs perfect, but when a rebooted the live CD don't want to boot anymore. Live CD sometimes gives kernel panic(`Kernel panic - not syncing attempted to kill init!`), sometimes it goes to busybox. I also tried with `acpi=off` option, but still kernel panics or dropping to busybox. Live CD is ok, because I already installed Ubuntu on some computer from the same CD.

I tried with **Ubuntu 11.04** live CD, but this version also gives kernel panics.

I also tested memory with `memtest` and computer past the test without errors.

Because the laptot have only 512 MB of RAM I tried to install **Lubuntu 10.04**, but when I boot Lubuntu from live CD it gives me kernel panic(`(process:289): GLib-WARNING **: getpwuid_r(): failed due to unknown user id (0)`, Num Lock light is blinking)

I sometimes get errors like `Authentication failure`, `Input/Output error` or

> `SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data
>   cache entry [c4d70c8]`
>
> `SQUASHFS error:
>   Unable to read page, block c4d70c8,
>   size e046`

The laptop is **Acer Aspire 5100** and it has:

- AMD Turion 64 (2.0 GHz, 512KB L2 cache)
- ATI Mobility Radeon X1300 128MB
- 60GB PATA HDD
- 512MB DDR2
- other things, like WLAN, bluetooth and so on

This laptop have Windows XP installed, but they are slow as hell(so slow, that they are impossible for normal use), so I want to install Ubuntu or Lubuntu, but it gives me various errors, while I am attempting to at least run live CD. Should I try with live USB?

Any help is appreciated. :)

**UPDATE**: I also tried Fedora 15(with Gnome shell) right now and it boots. Why the hell Ubuntu don't want to boot?

**UPDATE2**: It looks like the Ubuntu 10.04.2, Ubuntu 11.04 and Lubuntu 10.04 CDs are damagaed, acording to CD files check. But before I used this CDs on various computers, they just works. There must be something wrong with DVD-ROM on this laptop, because those CDs were OK before I tried it on this laptop. I am now downloading Ubuntu 10.04.2 iso image and I will make a liveUSB and then I will post results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burn a new CD, it has been damaged.

Boot again on the CD and choose the "Check the CD for errors" option. I expect a lot errors.

Comment: But I tried 3 various distros on 3 various CDs(Ubuntu 10.04.2, Ubuntu 11.04 and Lubuntu 10.04).
It looks like there is something wrong with DVD-reader, because those CD worked before, but now I tried "Check the CD for errors" option and lubuntu returns `Check finished: errors found in 7 files! I will try checking the CD for errors`for other 2 CDs and I will write here when the checking is done.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04.2: ´Check finished: errors found in 6 files!´ :/

Comment: There are special CDs available which can clean the drives. Could you verify if the `.iso` files weren't corrupted during download? Compare the output of `md5sum your-iso.iso` with http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.04/MD5SUMS

Comment: I burned this ISOs a long time ago and I have it on other computer(I don't have this computer at home right now). But the point is, that I burned those ISOs on CDs a long time ago and I installed those Operating System on other computers(every distro on other computer) without any problems, but now, when I tried to install it on this laptop, it just don't want to install. I am now downloading an Ubuntu 10.04.2 ISO file and I will try with liveUSB.

Comment: Optical media like CDs may become corrupted by time, but your CDs must have been of very bad quality or badly treated to die that fast.

Comment: I am now installing Ubuntu 10.04.2 from live USB. Ubuntu 10.04.2 booted without errors and Ubuntu is now installing on laptop. Accepting this answer. Thanks for your help.